# Ubuntu- How to start a service in runlevel 5

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have my executable file in service folder `/var/www/project/service/project.exe`. 
Currently I'm running on runlevel 2. I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86483/how-can-i-see-or-change-default-run-level) link to change my default runlevel to `5`.

Since this will be deployed on the cloud ,I want that it should start the service(`project.exe`) in runlevel 5 automatically, rather than manually.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: make some script under `/etc/init.d` (by copying and improving `/etc/init.d/skeleton`) and symlink it from `/etc/rc5.d/`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I'm a newbie in Linux, so can you kindly elaborate how can I improve the `skeleton` file. And moreover I have edited my question a bit. Now I want that since my s/w will be deployed on the cloud, then how should I approach this problem to initiate the service at runlevel5.

Comment: You need to take several days to learn more about Linux. Read several books. Study some free software Linux applications (e.g. `sash`). We don't have time to teach you all the basics. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlunuxprogramming.com/) and [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and several other good books or sites. Learn to use the [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) editor.

Comment: well, I'm not asking you to teach. I'm rather asking for the help which this forum provides. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Then, improve your question by showing your particular shell script code. Have a code related question which could be quickly answered.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) job. Write `/etc/init/project.conf` file:

```
start on runlevel 5
exec /var/www/project/service/project.exe
```

You probably want to specify [other options such as `description`, `stop on`, `respawn`, `setuid`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).